# What is the easiest way to use variables to create a DateTime with specific values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

What is the easiest way to use these variables:

```
year: "2011"
month: "8"
date: "28"
hours: "1"
minutes: "4"
```

to create a DateTime (i.e. `Sun, 28 Aug 2011 01:04:00 +1000`). The time zone does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::civil`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/date/DateTime.civil)

```
DateTime.civil(year.to_i, month.to_i, date.to_i, hours.to_i, minutes.to_i)
```

Change that to `to_i(10)` everywhere if you're worried about something like `"08"` being interpreted as an octal number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.civil`. Here is more info: [civil](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/civil/class)